# ADUM5028-5BRIZ inductivity problem

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I would like to build an isolated DC to DC converter for low current.
I have found this nice chip, but in the datasheet there are two inductances listed but not in uH or mH. It's is only in Ohms. Can you help me please?

Datasheet: https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/609/adum5028-1378717.pdf

Comment: on page 16. Two example inductance are listed. thanks for your help

Comment: Ferrite beads are usually listed in ohms but you have to be clearer. Embed an image of what precisely you are referring to. Red-line the parts of the text that confuse you. I can't see anything on pg 16 that particularly relates to the words in your question.

Comment: Table 20 gives you two good examples or what to use. You need any inductor that will give you the 1.8K impedance in the frequency range indicated and you want the lowest DC resistance possible to minimize losses.

Comment: It confuses me that this inductance is indicated in ohms. But I only find inductivities that are offered in uh or mh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very capable and unusual DC to DC converter.

Operation frequency is set **internally** to 180 MHz (!).
Power is transferred via an **internal** air cored transformer.

The inductances mentioned in table 20 (as ScienceGeyser indicated) are ferrite beads on the Vss and Ground leads. Their function is to isolate IC generated noise from the power lines. The beads play no part in the frequency determination.
They are specified to have an IMPEDANCE of >= 1.8 kohms across the frequency range 100 MHz to 1 GHz.
Manufacturers of appropriate ferrite beads will specify impedance with frequency in their data sheets.

Two examples of suitable beads are listed in table 20

Manufacturer ............ Part No.
Taiyo Yuden  ............. BKH1005LM182-T
Murata Electronics  ... BLM15HD182SN1

By examining datasheets for these products you should be able to find equivalent products if these are unavailable to you.

**___________________________________________**

**Digikey**

[BLM15HD182SN1D](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/murata-electronics/BLM15HD182SN1D/1948302?s=N4IgTCBcDaIEIBkCyBGArACQCIoBxgGUA5FAAhAF0BfIA) - 20 cents in 1's.

[BKH1005LM182-T](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/taiyo-yuden/BKH1005LM182-T/3195010?s=N4IgTCBcDaIEIGkASBGADGgrAGQLIoA4wBaAFRAF0BfIA) 10 cents in 1's

[ADUM5020](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/ADUM5020-5BRWZ/9485498) 5V version. $7.67 in 1's.
[Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM5020-5028.pdf)

Evaluation boards and application notes [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/result?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIYBMCuBbArABjBkBdAvkA)

---

Not quite to spec but reasonable

Taiyo Yuden FBMH3225HM202NT

from [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/taiyo-yuden/FBMH3225HM202NT/957842)

[image]

Comment: Can I use this : https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/de/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/742792090/732-1608-1-ND/1639552 ?

Comment: @fredmustermann No!!! see [datasheet](https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/742792090.pdf) - in the 1st graph you can see that the impedance is below 1800 Ohms across most of the required 100 MHz to 1 GHz. If you have access to Digikey (as appears to be the case) you'd be advised to use the recommended components - see links above that I provided. || The device you chose will do "something" but is far far less suitable than the recommended devices.

Comment: Note that kohms is correct and kOhms incorrect. See NIST comment thereon [here](https://www.nist.gov/pml/weights-and-measures/si-units-electric-current#:~:text=The%20SI%20unit%20of%20electric%20resistance%20is%20the%20ohm%20(%CE%A9).&text=Thus%20the%20names%20of%20all,material%20such%20as%20a%20title.)

Comment: Now I have made a schematic. Can this work ? Thanks for your answers.       https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzESM.png

Comment: Many [here](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_FB0004_Z-SMS.pdf) NONE are as good as wanted but some are probably good enough

Comment: Somewhere in [this selection guide](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/ferrite-beads-and-chips/841?s=N4IgjCBcpgbFoDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbRAGYBOcgJkpAIA5yB2MCJgFk9gAYHwYTi0bwAugQAOAFyggAytIBOASwB2AcxABfAjRqN%2B0EMkjps%2BIqXAA6RgAIA1gHkAFgFss9gAL2wvXgBZAAkALwEaJzdPHz8AkPC9G0iXDy9ffyCwiOSotNiWLMSQGmSAVjyYjPjspIrUqriinJZK9KaEnPro9rLmiRAZOQBhQgBXSQwcABMAVTUVaWcUQJw0LDGlHB1tbSA) which I've set to limit size and 100 MHz impedance there is probably something BUT 100 MHz performance is no guarantee of 1 GHz impedance. Happy searching:-) You need to look at each datasheet :-(

Comment: @fredmustermann  1. See updated answer 2. Two small good ones in series gives you a larger one - sort of :-) 3. Better - add a wire extension to a small one.

Comment: @fredmustermann Whether the circuit works should be asked as another question

Comment: Thanks for all comments. :)  I just ordered recomened inductances. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @fredmustermann My recommendation would be to go through the table and see if you can find something better than I found OR adapt the smaller ideal ones BUT the example I gave should work "well enough" to start - and maybe indefinitely. The datasheet recommended ones happen to be exceptionally good.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have found this                               
  https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/74269244182.pdf . This inductance has a big spectrum in the 100mhz to 1ghz area.

Comment: @fredmustermann That does look quite good. Notice mainly for interest and other applications - the 3rd graph - impedance with 200 mA DC in inductor. Still reasonable - and you should have MUCH less than 200 mA in the inductors.